# Quelle tournure est correcte « Je dois renouveler ma prescription » ou « Je dois faire renouveler ma prescription »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes

En parlant d’une prescription/ordonnance médicale. Si les deux se disent, quelle est la nuance?

Merci.

Answer (score 4):

Il n'est pas tout a fait exact de dire que les deux tournures sont synonymes: le patient ne peut renouveler lui-même sa prescription, il doit l'obtenir du médecin: C'est donc la deuxième forme, "faire renouveler", qui est correcte, la première étant un abus de langage.

Comment: Sauf si le patient est lui-même médecin auquel cas la première forme s'impose ;-)

Comment: à jiliagre: En effet! Où l'on voit que l'exception confirme la règle, ce qu'un bon grammairien comme vous ne pouvait laisser ignorer!

Comment: Si je suis pas médecin "je dois renouveler ma prescription" indique implicitement que je vais le demander à mon médecin.

Comment: @Archemar Oui, ça s'entend souvent mais comme l'a écrit BBBreiz, c'est un abus de langage. Comparer par exemple *je dois faire réviser ma voiture* et *je dois réviser ma voiture* ou *je dois faire examiner mon fils* et *je dois examiner mon fils*.

Answer (score 1):

Les deux se disent, la différence étant le sujet du verbe "renouveler". Si vous dites "je dois renouveler", cela signifie que vous accomplissez l'action vous-mêmes. Si vous dites "je dois faire renouveler", cela signifie que quelqu'un d'autre effectue l'action. Dans le cas d'une prescription, au moins deux personnes (vous et le médecin) participent à l'action, donc les deux tournures sont synonymes.